# Missing "objectId" from relation field

Tags: rest, parse-server

I am using Parse Server as backend for mobile app via REST. When I try to setup relation between objects, seems like something goes wrong and
`objectId` is missing from response object's relation field.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Sign Up

   ```
   curl -X "POST" ".../api/users" \
        -H "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" \
        -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MyKey" \
        -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MyAppID" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d $'{
     "username": "username",
     "password": "password"
   }'
   ```
2. Create Session

   ```
   curl -X "POST" ".../api/classes/session" \
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MyKey" \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MyAppID" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d $'{
   "title": "Session",
   "owner": {
   "objects": [
     {
       "__type": "Pointer",
       "className": "_User",
       "objectId": "RegisteredUserID"
     }
   ],
   "__op": "AddRelation"
   }
   }'
   ```
3. Get All Sessions

   ```
   curl ".../api/classes/session" \
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MyKey" \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MyAppID"
   ```

#### Expected Results

`results[0].owner` contains `objectId`.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "objectId": "xdTAyg6NXY",
      "title": "Session",
      "createdAt": "2017-04-22T21:20:08.657Z",
      "updatedAt": "2017-04-22T21:20:08.657Z",
      "owner": {
        "__type": "Relation",
        "className": "_User"
        "objectId": "RegisteredUserID"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Actual Outcome

`results[0].owner` does not contain `objectId`.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "objectId": "xdTAyg6NXY",
      "title": "Session",
      "createdAt": "2017-04-22T21:20:08.657Z",
      "updatedAt": "2017-04-22T21:20:08.657Z",
      "owner": {
        "__type": "Relation",
        "className": "_User"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Requesting Sessions by owner's id produces the same response as "Get All Sessions" above. The same response even with `include=owner` query parameter included.
Get Sessions Of User:

```
curl ".../api/classes/session?include=owner&where=%7B%22owner%22:%7B%22__type%22:%22Pointer%22,%22className%22:%22_User%22,%22objectId%22:%RegisteredUserID%22%7D%7D" \
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MyKey" \
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MyAppID"
```

Also, Parse Dashboard handles tap on relation properly.

#### Environment Setup

- **Server**

  - parse-server version: 2.3.8
  - Operating System:     macOS Sierra
  - Hardware:             MacBook Pro
  - Server: localhost
- **Database**

  - MongoDB version: 3.4.3
  - Storage engine:  wiredTiger
  - Hardware:        MacBook Pro
  - Server:           localhost

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Create Session instead:

```
curl -X "POST" ".../api/classes/session" \
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MyKey" \
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MyAppID" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d $'{
  "title": "Session",
  "owner": {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "_User",
    "objectId": "RegisteredUserID"
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thank you for editing, Alexandru. Seems like I don't understand how curl formatting works. Because some of them don't format with 4 spaces.